# How to I find $y(t)$ when the flow rate in is $=r$ and concentration of chemical $Y$ coming in is $=X$ grams per liter?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A tank initially contains $1$ liter of water and $628$ grams of chemical $Y$. 
A solution containing $X$ grams per liter of chemical $Y$ flows into the tank at the rate of r liter/hour. The mixture flows out of the tank a the rate of $4$ liters/hour. At the end of a six hour period the Lost Island chemical company wants to produce in the tank exactly $100$ grams of chemical $Y$ at a concentration of $4$ grams per liter. Find the flow rate $r$ in units of liters/hour and the concentration $X$ in units of grams/liter needed for the Lost Island chemical company to make this happen.

Here's how far I did. Let $y=$ amount of chemical $Y$ in the tank at time $t \geq 0$.  Let $v=$ volume of water in the tank at time $t$.
Where

$V=$ starting volume $+$ (Flow rate in $-$ Flow rate out)time
       $= 1 + (r-4)t
       = 1 + rt -4t$

$dy/dt =$ (concentration of chemical $Y$ coming in)(Flow rate coming in) - (concentration of chemical $Y$ coming out)(Flow rate coming out) = $X(r) - (y  /(1 + r t - 4 t))4$.